# How to check current page url in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to check if I am in certain domain, like this (in manifest.json for chrome extensions):

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["*://certain.site/*"],
  "js": ["some.js"]
}
```

But it seems like there are only dirty ways in javascript, like .split("/") which I don't want to use.
Is there a clean way to do it?

Comment: As clean as it possible - to use location object, it's avalible globally

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) for that. Like:

```
const currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
```

Now you can get the things like path and hostname from the `currentUrl`, like `currentUrl.pathname`.

To get only the file name you now can do:
`currentUrl.pathname.split('/').pop()`

Answer (score 0):

you get detail of URL

```js
console.log(location);
```

get current url

```js
console.log(location.href);
```